# About Islam.Stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion, quran

Salam'alaykum Muslim Members of Islam Stackexchange!

I would like to ask several questions about Islam. But my questions involve technical aspects of Islamic knowledge. I mean my questions are related to Hadith authenticity, sound knowledge of Arabic language, etc. So I know that only very knowledgeable person can answer my question. I am involved in Islamic apologetic, so I need to research various things related to Islam from various angels. I would like to know if the moderator @Medi1Saif and other users on this website have very good knowledge about Islam. Thanks!

Comment: Hello What kind of site is this  ?

Comment: TheMadHatter@ Are you Muslim?

Comment: Ask and you will see. However I'm quit busy these days.

Comment: I am Muslim of course. Haven't you seen me in Islam - StackExchange  ?

Comment: @TheMadHatter Just FYI one must not necesserily be a Muslim to post here ;).

Answer (score 3):

The Stack Exchange model of Q&A relies on the principle of collective knowledge, that with a large enough community one can ask a clear and focussed question to get exactly what information one needs from whoever has it, regardless of if they're a professional scholar, a casual user, a regular, or even an anonymous browser.

We are not a replacement for training with an actual scholar, or for seeking professional advice. We rely on users being able to answer according to their own knowledge and experience, and on the community at large to judge the quality of that answer through the use of voting, but questioners are still expected to put in the work of communicating exactly what they want and exercising their own critical skills to judge the answers received. Not all questions are suitable here: If it is important to you that you only receive answers from those with a minimum level of expertise or from a trained professional scholar, there are other sites for that.

That said, the best way to determine if anyone on Islam—Stack Exchange has the particular knowledge you seek is to simply ask your question on the main site and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Just to answer this.
On this website random people may answer questions about topics about Islam -preferably- based on their own knowledge or background or at least by good research which results with a certain background knowledge.
The quality of an answer is judged by the community by peer review.

There are as far as I can tell neither scholars nor people we may call students of knowledge (in Islamic sciences) on this site (I'm totally uncertain about the validity of my statement about the later).

However you may find a few people with a good background in about any specific topic of Islam, who either are hafidhs of the qur'an or interessted in Islamic topics or interested in doing research on these topics.

I -and I seek refuge in Allah from using "I" أعوذ بالله من قولة أنا- would count myself among the later: I've attended courses in a mosque about fiqh of 'Ibadat taking at least threee different fiqh books المرشد المعين, الرسالة لابن أبي زيد القيرواني, مختصر خليل, classes on Arabic language studying Alfiyat ibn Malik ألفية بن مالك and Matn al-Ajurumiya متن الآجرومية and some other classes on logic المنطق, on Osol al-Fiqh, on Eloquence (Balagha) البلاغة, on Tafssir, on Hadith (Terminolgy المصطلح and Riyadh as-Saliheen and At-Targhib wa at-Tarheeb) with a scholar -May Allah be pleased with him- I count as among the last knowledgable people on earth. My focus -at the time- however was rather more on fiqh, but when having time I attended the other classes too.
At this time of my life I was willing to become a student fo knowledge, but my teacher recommended me not to do so, further I should confess that I have an issue with memorization which would cause me huge problems to reach this goal.
After I started my university studies later I tried to discuss with him the possibility of creating a basic fatwa automat, as with a friend of mine we implemented a model of the book of taharah based on the views of Shafi'i and Maliki fiqh. Since then I started focusing on what is called al-Fiqh al-Muqarin الفقه المقارن, on Hadith sciences starting with studying al-Muwatta' of imam Malik, on qur'an sciences especially the topic of qira'aat (I've read several chapters of imam al-Suyuti's al-Itqaan and call the book of al-Zurqani and al-Buti my own and read both of them) this science has both a linguistic and a fiqh and even a tafseer part as a difference in a word may have a linguistic or grammatical impact and may even change the meaning or give an additional meaning which may have an impact on a fiqh rule...

In short you can only judge whether people are able to answer a question if you asked it.

Comment: I agree. Not everyone is good at everything. Someone might be much more knowledgeable about lets say Hajj over someone else or something. So waiting for an answer is the best way to go. And definitely I am no scholar, way too far from a scholar.